# Ubuntu 16.04 gets boot to GNU GRUB version 2.02`beta2-36ubuntu3.14. How to boot to my original desktop?

Tags: 16.04, lts

I updated my Ubuntu 16.04, but when rebooted, it booted into GUI GRUB. How to boot to my original desktop.

Please help me! My kernel version is 4.4.0-generic.

Comment: do you use a /boot partition ? do you use ext4 by default or another filesystem ? uefi or legacy bios ?

Comment: I used Legacy BIOS, and I don't know about my filesystem.